# Uncaught ReferenceError function is not defined with multiple javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to build a App which show a graph and a bar chart like below

[image]

As you can see I have to many data points to plot on the line chart area. So I must reduce/filter
the data to an higher aggregation level (like month / week instead of days) . Therefore I made the dropdown list (which you also can see in the picture below)
To realize this I use:

- MongoDB (Document database)
- NodeJS      (MiddleWare)
- D3JS           (Graphs)
- Jade           (Templates)

The page which is shown in the picture above loads 2 JavaScript files:

1. dataHandler.js

   Aggregate JSON from  tweets per day to  tweets per week or  per month
2. lineChartFull.js

building the linechar

You can find the scripts

**Index.jade**  https://github.com/ErikHoeven/WisdomAsAService/blob/master/views/Dashboard/index.jade)
**dataHandler.js**
https://github.com/ErikHoeven/WisdomAsAService/blob/master/public/views/Dashboard/dataHandler.js
**lineChartFull.js**
https://github.com/ErikHoeven/WisdomAsAService/blob/master/public/views/Dashboard/LineChartFull.js

the problem is when I call the function loadLineGraph which exist in the javascript file lineChartFull it returns the error “Uncaught ReferenceError function is not defined”

I hope you can help me to solve this problem.

Manny thanks

Erik

Comment: Do all your files load correctly? Do you see any other error or *404 not found* in browsers console?

Comment: Yes you need Node.js and grunt